# Yacc/Bison grammar for sequence of statements

Tags: grammar, bison, yacc

I'm trying to parse a sequence of statements, with the following rule: statements must be separated by at least one newline, and the sequence may be padded with at least zero newlines. For example,

```
\n
stmt\n
stmt\n
\n
stmt
```

So far I've come up with this Yacc grammar,

```
stmt_list:
    %empty
|   stmt_list stmt seps
;

seps:
    sep
| seps sep
;
```

but it doesn't match my example since my grammar expects a newline at the end.
Is there are standard way of parsing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple (and traditional) solution is to allow empty statements:

```
program  : statement
         | program '\n' statement

statement: %empty
         | statement_type_1
         | ...
```

That doesn't quite provide the same parse tree, since it forces you to ignore an empty statement :) But it has the virtue of being simple.

Otherwise, you're stuck with something like:

```
program       : statement_list opt_newlines

statement_list: opt_newlines
              | statement_list newlines statement

opt_newlines  : %empty
              | opt_newlines '\n'

newlines      : '\n' opt_newlines
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer is perfect. I'm not sure which of the two methods I should use, but the simple solution might be best since the "blank statement" action could look like `{}` and thus not affect the AST.