# Grammar for if statements in newline sensitive language

Tags: parsing, grammar, bison

I'm working on a language that is meant to read much like English, and having issues with the grammar for `if` statements. In case you are curious, the language is inspired by [HyperTalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperTalk), so I'm trying to make sure I match all the valid constructs in that language. The sample input I'm using that demonstrates all the possible `if` constructs can be viewed [here](https://gist.github.com/atjhc/fe860135af4e33c91bf7f38372ee8499). There are a lot, so I didn't want to inline the code.

I've removed most other constructs from the grammar to make it a bit easier to read, but basically statements look like this:

```
start
    : statementList
;

statementList
    : '\n'
    | statement '\n'
    | statementList '\n'
    | statementList statement '\n'
;

statement
    : ID
    | ifStatement
;
```

The shift/reduce conflicts I'm seeing are in the ifStatement rules:

```
ifStatement
    : ifCondition THEN statement
    | ifCondition THEN statement ELSE statement
    | ifCondition THEN statement ELSE '\n' statementList END IF
    | ifCondition THEN '\n' statementList END IF
    | ifCondition THEN '\n' END IF
    | ifCondition THEN '\n' ELSE statement
    | ifCondition THEN '\n' ELSE '\n' statementList END IF
    | ifCondition THEN '\n' statementList ELSE statement
    | ifCondition THEN '\n' statementList ELSE '\n' statementList END IF
// The following rules cause issues, but should be legal:
    | ifCondition THEN statement newlines ELSE statement
    | ifCondition THEN statement newlines ELSE '\n' statementList END IF
;

ifCondition
    : IF expression
    | IF expression '\n'
;

expression
    : TRUE
    | FALSE
;

newlines
    : '\n'
    | newlines '\n'
;
```

The problem is that I need to support this construct:

```
if true then statement # <- Any number of newlines
else statement
```

The problem (as I understand it) is that there isn't enough context to correctly determine whether to shift the `else`, or reduce just the `if true then statement` part without knowing what comes later (the end of the statement list, or another statement). Is this even parseable?

I have gists for the [parser](https://gist.github.com/atjhc/43f4240d15c5a8ac8c7aeadad24c3637), [scanner](https://gist.github.com/atjhc/28a1a711ec5d3be6c14c2b1f739c6ba3), and [sample input](https://gist.github.com/atjhc/fe860135af4e33c91bf7f38372ee8499) to try out.

Comment: So the following is not in your list: `if true then statement \n else \n statement \n statement \n end if`? I was so much expecting to see it that I imagined the production which would recognise it. I've now removed that fantasy from my answer.

Comment: Actually you are right! Looks like I missed that case in the test input. There doesn't seem to be a ton of great documentation about the grammar, so I've had to guess and check a bit with the original software.

Comment: Updated the question with fixes for issues @rici pointed out, but restated what I think is the root cause.

Comment: Ok, I think I've got this. Just want to do a few more tests.

Comment: I'm impressed! I got pretty close by having statements consume all the newlines (rather than having the statementList responsible for this), but that made inline statements (i.e. constructions like: `if true then statement else statement`) not parse.

Comment: I finally posted the grammar. Sorry it took me so long. Actually, I wouldn't mind doing a better test suite, but it did pass all your tests and an equal number of additional ones I wrote so I hope it's all OK. I think I should better document some of the choices I made, though. I'll try to get back to it over the next couple of days. If there is some specific issue, please let me know here.

Comment: This is an amazing response! Thanks for the writeup, once I've had a chance to digest it, I'll let you know how it went.

Comment: I'm sure it's no surprise to hear your solution worked perfectly!

Comment: That's gratifying. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting this right is surprisingly difficult, so I've tried to annotate the steps. There are a lot of annoying details.

At its core, this is just a manifestation of the dangling else ambiguity, whose resolution is pretty well-known (force the parser to always shift the `else`). The solution below resolves the ambiguity in the grammar itself, which is unambiguous.

The basic principle that I've used here is the one outlined several decades ago in [*Principles of Compiler Design*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_Compiler_Design) by Alfred Aho and Jeffrey Ullman (the so-called "Dragon book", which I mention since its authors were recently [granted the Turing award](https://awards.acm.org/about/2020-turing) precisely for that and their other influential works). In particular, I use the terms "matched" and "unmatched" (rather than "open" and "closed", which are also popular) because that's the way I learned it.

It is also possible to solve this grammar problem using precedence declarations; indeed, that often turns out to be much simpler. But in this particular case, it's not easy to work with operator precedence because the relevant token (the `else`) can be preceded by an arbitrary number of newline tokens. I'm pretty sure you could still construct a precedence-based solution, but there are advantages to using an unambiguous grammar, including the ease of porting to a parser generator which doesn't use the same precedence algorithm, and the fact that it is possible to analyze mechanically.

The basic outline of the solution is to divide all statements into two categories:

- "matched" (or "closed") statements, which are complete in the sense that it is not possible to extend the statement with an `else` clause. (In other words, every `if…then` is matched by a corresponding `else`.) These
- "unmatched" (or "open") statements, which could have been extended with an `else` clause. (In other words, at least one `if…then` clause is not matched by an `else`.) Since the unmatched statement is a complete statement, it cannot be immediately followed by an `else` token; had an `else` token appeared, it would have served to extend the statement.

Once we manage to construct grammars for these two categories of statement, it's only necessary to figure out which uses of `statement` in the ambiguous grammar can be followed by `else`. In all of these contexts, the non-terminal `statement` must be replaced with the non-terminal `matched-statement`, because only matched statements can be followed by `else` without interacting with it. In other contexts, where `else` could not be the next token, either category of statement is valid.

So the essential grammar style is (taken from the Dragon book):

```
           stmt → matched_stmt
                | unmatched_stmt
   matched_stmt → "if" expr "then" matched_stmt "else" matched_stmt
                | other_stmt
unmatched_stmt  → "if" expr "then" matched_stmt "else" unmatched_stmt
                | "if" expr "then" stmt
```

`other_stmt` is anything other than a conditional statement. Or, to be more precise, anything other than a compound statement which precisely ends with a `stmt`.

In Hypertalk, as far as I know, `if` statements are the only compound statements which can end with a statement. Other compound statements are precisely terminated with an `end X`, which effectively closes the statement. But in other languages, such as C, there are a variety of compound statements, and most of these need to be divided into "matched" and "unmatched" depending precisely on whether their terminating substatement is (recursively) matched or unmatched.

One thing I want to note here, which is apparent from that outline grammar if you look at it a bit sideways, is that the `if…then…else` part of the `if` statement is grammatically similar to a bracketed prefix operator. That is, both `matched_stmt` and `unmatched_stmt` are similar to the right-recursive rule for unary minus:

```
unary → '-' unary
      | atom
```

which in turn could be written in an Extended BNF dialect which allows Kleene stars as

```
unary → ('-')* atom
```

If we were to do that transformation to Aho&Ullman's grammar, we'd end up with:

```
  if_then_else → "if" expr "then" matched_stmt "else"
  matched_stmt → (if_then_else)* other_stmt
unmatched_stmt → (if_then_else)* "if" expr "then" stmt
```

That makes it reasonably clear how to implement this grammar with a top-down recursive-descent parser. (A bit of left-factoring is needed, but it still ends up being similar to the unary minus grammar.) I'm not planning on developing this thought further in this answer, but I think that the EBNF conversion helps guide the intuitions about how this grammar actually works to undangle the else.

It was also really helpful in figuring out how to deal with newlines. The key insight (for me) was that statements must end with a newline. The one exception is the condensed single-line version of the `if` command. But that exception only happens just before an `else` token (and only when the `then` which it matches in on the same line). In this grammar, that case is implemented with the `inner-matched` non-terminal, assisted by the fact that one-line statements (like `do-statement`) lack the terminating newline. The newline which terminates one-line statements is added in the recursive base case for `matched` (`single-statement NL`); that's the only place it needs to be handled. Multi-line compound statements are all defined with a terminating newline (see, for example, `repeat-statement`).

Most of the rest of the complications deal with the variety of syntactic forms. The only one which is really interesting is the handling of blocks after a `then` token at the end of a line. That block can be terminated in two ways:

- with an `end if` line, without an `else` clause. This is treated as a "matched" case, since it clearly could not be extended with an `else` clause.
- with an `else` clause (which could be a single line `else` or a block `else`, where the `else` token is at the end of the line). But here there is a possible ambiguity; if the last statement in the block is an unmatched `if`, then an `else` line should extend that statement, rather than terminating the block. That's not really different from the rest of the matched/unmatched logic; to implement it, I created two different `block` non-terminals, one ending with a matched statement and the other ending with an unmatched statement. And then, as usual, only the matched block can be used before an `else`.

(I found the new counterexample generator in bison 3.7.6 extremely helpful here; my initial attempt just used `block` because I'd failed to notice the ambiguity. But it is a real ambiguity, and it lead to a shift-reduce conflict whose origins seemed mysterious. Once I saw the counterexample produced by the counterexample generator -- which showed the conflict happening inside a `block` following an `if-then` -- the problem became a lot more evident.)

The alternation between `matched-block` and `unmatched-block` is a simple example of the correspondence between grammar productions and state machines. The two non-terminals represent the two states in a very simple state machine, whose state records a single bit: whether or not the last statement was matched. The non-terminals must be right-recursive for this to work, which is a deviation from the usual "prefer left-recursion" heuristic for building LALR(1) grammars.

OK, with that overlong preamble, here's the grammar. In the interests of compactification, I simplified expressions down to just variables and boolean constants, included only one simple statement (**do** *expr*) and included only one other compound statement (**repeat until** *expr* / *block* / **end repeat**). (The last one is there as a placeholder.)

```
program : block

block   : %empty
        | matched-block
        | unmatched-block

NL      : '\n'
        | NL '\n'

matched-block
        : block matched

unmatched-block
        : block unmatched

simple-statement
        : "do" expression

repeat-statement
        : "repeat" "until" expression NL block "end" "repeat" NL

matched : if-then matched else-matched
        | if-then inner-matched else-matched
        | if-then NL matched-block else-matched
        | if-then NL else-matched
        | if-then NL block "end" "if" NL
        | repeat-statement
        | simple-statement NL

inner-matched
        : %empty
        | simple-statement
        | if-then inner-matched "else" inner-matched

unmatched
        : if-then matched
        | if-then unmatched
        | if-then inner-matched "else" unmatched
        | if-then matched "else" unmatched

if-then : "if" expression NL "then"
        | "if" expression "then"

else-matched
        : "else" NL block "end" "if" NL
        | "else" matched

expression
        : ID
        | "true"
        | "false"
```

#### Previous answer (to original question, only visible in the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/66876982/1))

There is an obvious ambiguity between

```
ifCondition THEN statement EOL ELSE statement
```

and

```
ifCondition THEN EOL statementList ELSE statement
```

Recall that

```
statement: %empty
statementList: statement
```

with the result that both `statement` and `statementList` can derive the empty sequence. So both of the above productions for `ifStatement` can derive:

```
ifCondition THEN EOL ELSE statement
```

The parser has no way to know whether there is an empty `statement` before the `EOL` or an empty `statementList` after it. (You might not care which of these is chosen but parsers obsess about this kind of decision.)

Nullable productions are often problematic. Where possible, avoid them. Instead of letting `statement` derive empty, indicate explicitly where an empty statement might go by adding a rule where the optional statement is omitted. And consider rewriting `statementList` so that it must end with an `EOL`, which I think was your intention anyway (but perhaps I'm wrong).

Comment: I'll see if I can rework the grammar a bit to remove the nullable productions. I've actually had a bit of a tough time just getting newline separated statements/definitions working correctly. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866947/yacc-bison-grammar-for-sequence-of-statements) helped but the alternative proposal wasn't working for me.

Comment: @james: i guess in seven years of seeing the problems people habe writing grammars, my views on how best to do that have changed :-)

Comment: @james: by the way, if you're working from http://www.jaedworks.com/hypercard/scripts/hypertalk-bnf.html then you'll find that there are some ambiguities in that grammar. I think it includes the one I mentioned in this answer.

Comment: I was using that reference to get started, but abandoned it eventually because of missing rules and some ambiguities. Since then I've just been working off the original manuals (which don't have a formal grammar spec, just descriptions of how the language works). I'm starting to wonder if it would be easier to write my own parser than continue struggling with Bison.

Comment: @james: i think you can parse hypertalk with recursive descent. But if you could do that, bison wouldn't be a problem either. The problem is correctly specifying the language without ambiguities. With R.D. you can just ignore ambiguities but you're left with "the language is whatever my parser happens to recognise." I don't think that bothered the original implementors and it might not bother you, so my prejudices need not be taken into account.

Comment: I *think* I have it solved. I updated the [gist here](https://gist.github.com/atjhc/43f4240d15c5a8ac8c7aeadad24c3637) with the current version. I removed the nullable statement as you suggested, and added two rules to help disambiguate these productions: `ifCondition THEN statement '\n' statement` and `ifCondition THEN statement '\n' ELSE`

Comment: @James: Cool! `multiIf` could use a left-factoring, no? :-) But it looks reasonable. I just have one question, which maybe you can answer. You allow a `statementList` to end with a `statement` (i.e. without a `\n`). Is that actually necessary? (That's the question.) That would correspond to an input like `if true then \n statement \n statement end if` or `if true then \n statement \n statement else \n statement \n statement end if`. Those don't appear in your examples (`else` and `end if` after a statementList are always line-initial), and it looks ugly enough to ban, at least to my eye.

Comment: Does left-factoring help with LALR parsers? Good question, and you are right: I need to add a '\n' after the last `statementList` rule. Also, looks like my solution breaks `if true then statement $end` (or any other finishing token for the `statementList`)

Comment: Left-factoring has little effect on LALR parsers. But it can make the grammar tidier for human readers :-)